# Proper understanding of dependency array in useEffect when working with Redux Thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-effect, redux-thunk

I am starting to learn Redux and the thunk library.

I have an Actions.js which holds the function:

```
export const fetchInventory = (user_id) => {
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchInventoryData());
    fetch("url", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },

      //make sure to serialize your JSON body
      body: JSON.stringify({ user_id }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        saveInventory(res);
        dispatch(fetchInventorySuccess(res));
      })
      .catch((err) => dispatch(fetchInventoryFailure(err)));
  };
};
```

and a Container.js with the useEffect as follows:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (inventory.inventoryData.length > 0) return;
    else if (user_id) fetchInventory(user_id);
    else return [];
  }, [user_id]);
```

EsLint gives me a warning that I am missing fetchInventory and inventory in the dependency array. However, since inventory is the state that this fetch will update, including it throws us into an infinite fetch. Also, the user_id necessary here is something that comes from a fetch request prior to this one. In a situation like this, what would go into the dependency array and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inventory` should certainly be included in the dependency array since it is ***referenced*** in the hook callback (*and likely also the `fetchInventory` action creator, for the same reason*).

I believe the issue here is an improper guard clause (i.e. condition) for which you are calling the callback that updates state (and dependency).

The `if-else-if-else` is the issue. when the first condition fails, because `inventory.inventoryData.length` is non-zero, the second condition is checked, and sure enough there's a defined `user_id` value and the callback is invoked.

From what I can gather, the condition you want is "if there ***is no*** inventory data ***AND*** there ***is*** a user id, then fetch inventory, otherwise do nothing".

Try simplifying your condition and branching factor.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!inventory.inventoryData.length && user_id) {
    fetchInventory(user_id)
  }
}, [fetchInventory, inventory.inventoryData, user_id]);
```

Comment: Thank you that actually did the trick. I have a hard time understanding this, may you elaborate further on why my existing version created the same behavior as yours and why of course yours is the proper way to do it and consequences of doing it like mine?

Comment: @SeymurMammadov It's the `if-else-if-else`, when the first condition fails, because `inventory.inventoryData.length` is non-zero, the second condition is checked, and sure enough there's a defined `user_id` value and the callback is invoked. If you tucked the second condition inside the first condition's block then I suspect it'd work. The last `else` is doing nothing. I updated my answer to also include the explanation.

Comment: How about in a scenario where you receive object prop called modal and you do this in a component:
  const [activity, setActivity] = useState({
    interaction: [],
    title: "",
    body: "",
    company_id: 162,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setActivity({ ...activity, ...modal });
  }, [modal]);

ESlint complains and says to add activity but doing so throws into infinite loop. My question is more geared towards why ESLint is complaining here when clearly you can't add that.

Comment: @SeymurMammadov Other than it's a bit of an anti-pattern to store props into local component state, I see no issue where since nothing in `activity` state is in the effect's dependency array. Oh, yeah, you should use a functional state update to update from the previous state, i.e. `useEffect(() => { setActivity(activity => ({ ...activity, ...modal })); }, [modal]);`. This removes the external dependency on `activity` in the callback.

Comment: Thank you @Drew Reese, yeah not sure the linter might be acting up. It still shows "React hook has a missing dependency 'activity'. Appreciate it mate

Comment: @SeymurMammadov The linter isn't very bright, and isn't necessarily "smart enough" to see that a value referenced within the hook's callback is ***actually*** updated by a function also called in the callback.

Comment: @SeymurMammadov If you've further questions/issues, post a new question and feel free to ping (at) me here in a comment with a link to the new question and I can take a look when available. Cheers.